# Visual studio not focusing to specflow scenario when double clicked on a test in test explorer

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, specflow

I have too many specflow scenarios in my solution. These scenarios are displayed in visual studio test explorer. But when I double click on the test case it doesn't take me to the feature file where that corresponding scenario is written. Every time I have to manually find and open the feature file from solution explorer.

But for unit tests, it's working fine.

I'm using VS2017, mstest v2 and specflow 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Specflow & VS 2019. I closed my VS instance, went to my local drive & looked for all the **.testlog** files. I deleted all of them. Then after that I opened my solution on VS, the issue was resolved. 
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed with latest Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5.2, i tried and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).